# Installing gstreamer NVIDIA Plugins on Ubuntu

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia

I am trying to install the official NVIDIA Codecs for GStreamer. I have the following setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Gstreamer 1.14.5
- NVIDIA QUADRO P2000
- NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100
- CUDA Version 10.2.89
- NVIDIA Video_Codec_SDK_9.0.20

I followed this installation guide http://lifestyletransfer.com/how-to-install-nvidia-gstreamer-plugins-nvenc-nvdec-on-ubuntu/

After the installation I can use nvdec in the following command without a problem:

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=jumanji.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! nvdec ! glimagesink sync=false`

Howerver, when trying to use the encoder nvh264enc with the following command:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=10000 ! nvh264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=video.mp4`

I get the following error:

`Error: from Element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvH264Enc:nvh264enc0: The Supported library  could not be initialized. gstvideoencoder.c(1627): gst_video_encoder_change_state (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvH264Enc:nvh264enc0: Failed to open encoder`

I have tried to look for similar error reports without luck. Any lead on how to solve it would be deeply appreciated.

EDIT:

By executing the previous pipeline with the Debug level --gst-debug-level=5 I can read the following error message in the log:

> nvenc gstnvenc.c:267:gst_nvenc_create_cuda_context: Initialising CUDA..
> 0:00:00.523634157  7971 0x56375974c600 INFO                   nvenc gstnvenc.c:276:gst_nvenc_create_cuda_context: Initialised CUDA
> 0:00:00.523654036  7971 0x56375974c600 INFO                   nvenc gstnvenc.c:284:gst_nvenc_create_cuda_context: 1 CUDA device(s) detected
> 0:00:00.523702909  7971 0x56375974c600 INFO                   nvenc gstnvenc.c:290:gst_nvenc_create_cuda_context: GPU #0 supports NVENC: yes (Quadro P2000) (Compute SM 6.1)
> 0:00:00.646223264  7971 0x56375974c600 INFO                   nvenc gstnvenc.c:312:gst_nvenc_create_cuda_context: Created CUDA context 0x5637599d78f0
> 0:00:00.646239492  7971 0x56375974c600 ERROR                  nvenc gstnvbaseenc.c:437:gst_nv_base_enc_open: Failed to create NVENC encoder session, ret=15
> 0:00:00.646262028  7971 0x56375974c600 INFO                   nvenc gstnvenc.c:320:gst_nvenc_destroy_cuda_context: Destroying CUDA context 0x5637599d78f0
> 0:00:00.755491991  7971 0x56375974c600 WARN            videoencoder gstvideoencoder.c:1627:gst_video_encoder_change_state: error: Failed to open encoder

Answer (score 0):

You need to build and install the gst plugins bad with nvidia encoders/decoders enabled. They don't exist until you do. This involves downloading and installing cuda, cloning the repo, building the plugins, installing in the relevant directories.